# flask sqlalchemy - Insert many-to-many only with entities IDs

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have the many-to-many relationship as suggested in http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/ :

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('page_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('page.id'))
)

class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
    backref=db.backref('pages', lazy='dynamic'))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I have a Page fully identified by:

```
page = Page.query.filter_by(id=value).one()
```

I also have **list** of tags **ids**. The current working code is:

```
for id in tag_ids:
    tag = Tag.query.filter_by(id=id).one() #wanna avoid this
    page.tags.append(tag)
```

For more complex tables, this can be inefficient, since it will make unnecessary queries to identify the tag entities, just to satisfy the SQLAlchemy architecture. So: **How can I insert into the tags table only by providing the Page id and the Tag id?**

I've tried, without success, this:

```
tags.insert().values(tag_id=value1, page_id=value2)
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
page_id = Page.query.get(value).id

for tag_id in tag_ids:
    db.session.connection().execute(tags.insert.values(tag_id=tag_id, page_id=page_id))
```

Comment: It would be db.session.connection() instead of db.session.connection . Also, this solution only works if the Page entity already exists in the database. I couldn't find a way to create a Page and its tags on a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your correct. The tags is a association table. The fields in it are all foreign key.